# Data missing (files) in my django serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have an issue, some data are missing in my serializer (in validate and create functions).
My Model:

```py
class PostsImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts/images")
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        "socialmedia.Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts_images"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "PostsImage"
        verbose_name_plural = "PostsImages"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image


class PostsAttachedFile(models.Model):
    attached = models.FileField(upload_to="posts/attached")
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        "socialmedia.Post",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="posts_attached_files",
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "PostsAttachedFile"
        verbose_name_plural = "PostsAttachedFiles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.attached


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    business_sector = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=BUSINESS_SECTOR_CHOICES)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField()
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location_radius = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My serializer:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostsImageSerializer(many=True, source="posts_images", required=False)
    attached_files = PostsAttachedFileSerializer(
        many=True, source="posts_attached_files", required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print(attrs)
        author = attrs.get("author")
        location_type = attrs.get("location_type")
        location_radius = attrs.get("location_radius")
        valid_until = attrs.get("valid_until")
        user = self.context["request"].user

        if author and author != user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"author": "You can't create post for another user"}
            )

        if location_type == "local" and not location_radius:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {
                    "location_radius": "You must provide location radius if location type is local",
                }
            )

        if valid_until and valid_until.timestamp() < datetime.now().timestamp():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"valid_until": "Valid until must be in the future"}
            )
        print("#### validation ok")
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        images = None
        attached_files = None
        if "posts_images" in validated_data.keys():
            images = validated_data.pop("posts_images")
        if "posts_attached_files" in validated_data.keys():
            attached_files = validated_data.pop("posts_attached_files")
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        images_from_files = self.context["request"].FILES.getlist("posts_images")
        print(images_from_files)
        print(self.context["request"].data)
        if images_from_files:
            for image in images_from_files:
                PostsImage.objects.create(post=post, image=image)
        if attached_files:
            for attached_file in attached_files:
                PostsAttachedFile.objects.create(post=post, attached_file=attached_file)
        return post

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        images = None
        attached_files = None
        if "posts_images" in validated_data.keys():
            images = validated_data.pop("posts_images")
        if "posts_attached_files" in validated_data.keys():
            attached_files = validated_data.pop("posts_attached_files")
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        if images and type(images) == list:
            instance.posts_images.all().delete()
            for image in images:
                PostsImage.objects.create(post=instance, **image)
        if attached_files and type(attached_files) == list:
            instance.posts_attached_files.all().delete()
            for attached_file in attached_files:
                PostsAttachedFile.objects.create(post=instance, **attached_file)
        return instance
```

My viewset:

```py
class PostModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)

    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

And finally my test code:

```py
class PostModelViewSetTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            email="testuser@test.com", password="testpassword"
        )
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

    def test_create_post(self):
        tmp_image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            "file.jpg", b"file_content", content_type="image/jpg"
        )
        img_path = f"{CURRENT_DIR}/socialmedia/tests/default.png"
        image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            name="test_image.jpg",
            content=open(img_path, "rb").read(),
            content_type="image/jpeg",
        )
        data = {
            "author": self.user.id,
            "location_type": "local",
            "location": "nord",
            "location_radius": 5,
            "valid_until": datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1),
            "content": "content",
            "title": "title",
            "business_sector": "IT",
            "images": [
                {"image": image},
                {"image": image},
                {"image": image},
                {"image": image},
            ],
        }

        response = self.client.post("/socialmedia/posts/", data, format="multipart")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Post.objects.count(), 1)
        print(PostsImage.objects.all())
        self.assertEqual(PostsImage.objects.count(), 4)
        post = Post.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(post.author, self.user)
        self.assertEqual(post.posts_images.count(), 4)
```

In my test, I want to create a post with several images. If I remove the images, it works fine, but if I leave them in, the post object is created, but not the PostsImage. The test therefore fails, because there aren't 4 PostsImage objects created.

The PostsImage objects are not created because if I do a print in my serializer (`print(attrs)` in the validate)

I get this: `.OrderedDict([('title', 'title'), ('content', 'content'), ('business_sector', 'IT'), ('valid_until', datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 18, 9, 34, 22, 220328, tzinfo=zoneinfo. ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))), ('location_type', 'local'), ('location', 'nord'), ('location_radius', 5), ('author', <User: >))])`

Missing "images" or "posts_images".

If in my test I change `response = self.client.post("/socialmedia/posts/", data, format="multipart")` by `response = self.client.post("/socialmedia/posts/", data, format="json")`, I can see posts_images in my serializers but it doesn't work because they are files.

So I have tried to use `images_from_files = self.context["request"].FILES.getlist("posts_images")` but self.context["request"].FILES is empty

--- EDIT
if I add in my PostSerializer :

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("INIT:", kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can read in the cli:

```
INIT: {'data': <QueryDict: {'author': ['1'], 'location_type': ['local'], 'location': ['nord'], 'location_radius': ['5'], 'valid_until': ['2023-09-18 16:28:08.554737'], 'content': ['content'], 'title': ['title'], 'business_sector': ['IT'], 'images': ["{'image': <SimpleUploadedFile: image.JPG (image/jpeg)>}", "{'image': <SimpleUploadedFile: image2.JPG (image/jpeg)>}"]}>, 'context': {'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/socialmedia/posts/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <socialmedia.views.PostModelViewSet object at 0x7fcce092c290>}}
```

The images object is a list of String ! :( How to change that ?

----EDIT2
I understand the issue, it's not possible to send a dict with data if I use the multipart format.
I need to send:

```
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author"

1
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_type"

local
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location"

nord
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_radius"

5
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="valid_until"

2023-09-18T17:55:41.165733
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

content
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

title
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="business_sector"

IT
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="image.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Binary Data for image.JPG>
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="image2.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Binary Data for image2.JPG>
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg--
```

instead of:

```
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author"

1
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_type"

local
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location"

nord
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location_radius"

5
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="valid_until"

2023-09-18T17: 55: 41.165733
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

content
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

title
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="business_sector"

IT
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"

{\'image\': <SimpleUploadedFile: image.JPG (image/jpeg)>
}
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"

{\'image\': <SimpleUploadedFile: image2.JPG (image/jpeg)>
}
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg--
```

Unfortunately the DjangoJsonConverter convert the `data` to the 2nd multipart payload :(
I don't know how to have the 1st one.

----EDIT3
I found a solution \o/
I created 2 Serializers:

```py
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = PostsImageSerializer(many=True, source="posts_images", required=False)
    attached_files = PostsAttachedFileSerializer(
        many=True, source="posts_attached_files", required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.ListField(
        required=False, child=serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    )
[...]
```

I use the 1st one for list or retrieve request and the 2nd one for any others requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create fake Images as many you want in setup method, every time test will run, your images will create automatically.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

        image = BytesIO()
        Image.new('RGB', (100, 100)).save(image, 'JPEG')
        image.seek(0)
        self.image_1 = SimpleUploadedFile('image.JPG', image.getvalue())
```

This is how you create single image. You can loop through this and create more than one images.
Make sure all data should be set in setUp method that's best practice to write test cases.

Comment: Thank you, I moved the image generation in the setUp. But I have always the issue. The content of validated_data don't contain "images" : .OrderedDict([('title', 'title'), ('content', 'content'), ('business_sector', 'IT'), ('valid_until', datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 18, 15, 17, 14, 680547, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Paris'))), ('location_type', 'local'), ('location', 'nord'), ('location_radius', 5), ('author', <User:  >)])